# Installing of jdk and jre 1.8 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, package-management, java, jdk, jre

I tried with all the types possible of installing Java
for example:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Even I deleted the `/usr/lib/java` and `/lib/jvm` folders. I also tried installing but it doesn't work.

But in all these I'm getting a same error of :

```
E: The package jre1.8.0-77 needs to be reinstalled.
```

I can't find an archive for it.

Any help please?

Comment: What about `sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk`?

Comment: same error @Zacharee1

Comment: Can you paste a full terminal output from the command?

Comment: http://s31.postimg.org/nqifrith7/java.png    @Zacharee1

Comment: OK. `sudo apt-get purge jre1.8.0-77` then the command above.

Comment: http://s31.postimg.org/5attzr6wr/java1.png  @Zacharee1

Comment: `sudo apt-get clean || sudo apt-get autoclean || sudo apt-get update || sudo apt-get install -f || sudo dpkg --configure -a || sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: http://s31.postimg.org/u1h7op9kr/java3.png   @Zacharee1  can you help in solving it through teamviewer or something? pls

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not so sure there's very much to be done. To be honest, your best option is a fresh reinstallation.

Comment: Okay @Zacharee1 thank you .. i will reinstall my 14.04 ..

Comment: Actually, can I recommend you install 16.04? It literally just came out today and it's LTS, like 14.04.

Comment: oh wow thank you :) .. i didn't know about that.. i will download it..  @Zacharee1

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Install ppa-purge with `sudo apt-get install ppa-purge`

Then bash `sudo ppa-purge ppa:webupd8team/java`

Try to open your filemanager with gksu and delete the Java folders.

Next step is to install the ppa again WITHOUT the -y option.

You should be able to eccept the terms of service and install java.

If you are done check with `java -version` and `javac -version` if you are good to go.

Cheers